# Github Actions get image hash

Tags: docker, github-actions

I'd like to push an image to a registry and tag it with a hash of the contents of the image. So if the Action runs and builds an image thats identical in content, the hash will be the same. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Not sure I understand. When you push an image to a registry, the manifest contains a SHA256 digest of the image. It's what lets you pull images like `docker pull image@sha256:abc1234....` -- I'm not sure I see the point of tagging the image with a content hash because one is already calculated for you.

Comment: I use terraform to deploy to k8s so if the image name doesn't change terraform won't deploy it because the contents didn't change

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this based on the layers hashes:

- First, you get the SHA256 hash of each layer e and concatenate them together
- And then take the SHA256 hash of the concatenated string and output the final hash

```
#!/bin/bash

hash=$(docker inspect --format='{{range .RootFS.Layers}}{{.}} {{end}}' "$1" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d '\n')


echo -n "$hash" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}'
```

Run script to get hash and use this hash to tag image:

```
./script.sh <image name or ID>
```